# NSIS - How can I write on a .txt file the option that the user choosed

Tags: nsis

I got this script (Author: Red Wine), that shows a droplist with the available drivers that the user can choose to install the files. I need to get the option that the user choosed and write it down on a .txt file. How can I do that? (Example: if the user choosed C:\, just right "C:\" there)

```
!define SIZE "100" ;add here total uncompressed data size in Mb of your application
!define APPNAME "My Application"
Name '${APPNAME}'
OutFile 'test.exe'
LicenseData '${NSISDIR}\License.txt'
LicenseBkColor 0xFFFFFF
ShowInstDetails show
AllowRootDirInstall true

!include WinMessages.nsh
!include FileFunc.nsh
!insertmacro GetDrives
!insertmacro DriveSpace

Page License
Page Custom CustomCreate CustomLeave
Page InstFiles

Section "boo"
        SetOutPath '$INSTDIR'
SectionEnd

Function CustomCreate
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Settings' 'NumFields' '6'

         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 1' 'Type' 'Label'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 1' 'Left' '5'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 1' 'Top' '5'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 1' 'Right' '-6'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 1' 'Bottom' '17'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 1' 'Text' \
         'Select Installation drive:'

         StrCpy $R2 0
         StrCpy $R0 ''
         ${GetDrives} "HDD" GetDrivesCallBack

         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 2' 'Type' 'DropList'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 2' 'Left' '30'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 2' 'Top' '26'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 2' 'Right' '-31'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 2' 'Bottom' '100'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 2' 'Flags' 'Notify'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 2' 'State' '$R1'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 2' 'ListItems' '$R0'

         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 3' 'Type' 'Label'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 3' 'Left' '5'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 3' 'Top' '109'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 3' 'Right' '59'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 3' 'Bottom' '119'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 3' 'Text' \
         'Space required:'

         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 4' 'Type' 'Label'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 4' 'Left' '60'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 4' 'Top' '109'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 4' 'Right' '-5'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 4' 'Bottom' '119'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 4' 'Text' \
         '${SIZE} Mb'

         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 5' 'Type' 'Label'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 5' 'Left' '5'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 5' 'Top' '120'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 5' 'Right' '59'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 5' 'Bottom' '130'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 5' 'Text' \
         'Space available:'

         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 6' 'Type' 'Label'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 6' 'Left' '60'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 6' 'Top' '120'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 6' 'Right' '-5'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 6' 'Bottom' '130'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 6' 'Text' \
         '$R3 Mb'

         push $0
         InstallOptions::Dialog '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini'
         pop $0
         pop $0
FunctionEnd

Function CustomLeave
        ReadIniStr $0 '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Settings' 'State'
        StrCmp $0 '2' 0 next
        ReadIniStr $0 '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 2' 'State'
        StrCpy $0 $0 3
        ${DriveSpace} "$0" "/D=F /S=M" $R3
        WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 6' 'Text' \
        '$R3 Mb'
        ReadIniStr $0 '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 6' 'HWND'
        SendMessage $0 ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 'STR:$R3 Mb'
        Abort

     next:
        ReadIniStr $0 '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 2' 'State'
        StrCpy '$INSTDIR' '$0'
FunctionEnd

Function GetDrivesCallBack
         ${DriveSpace} "$9" "/D=F /S=M" $R4
         IntCmp $R4 '${SIZE}' end end def
      def:
         StrCmp $R2 '0' 0 next
         StrCpy $R3 '$R4'
         StrCpy $R1 '$9${APPNAME}'
         IntOp $R2 $R2 + 1
      next:
         StrCpy $R0 '$R0$9${APPNAME}|'
      end:
     Push $0
FunctionEnd

Function .onInit
         InitPluginsDir
         GetTempFileName $0
         Rename $0 '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini'
FunctionEnd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `CustomLeave` function as following:

```
Function CustomLeave
        ReadIniStr $0 '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Settings' 'State'
        StrCmp $0 '2' 0 next
        ReadIniStr $0 '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 2' 'State'
        strcpy $R0  $0
        StrCpy $0 $0 3
        FileOpen $1 'Myfile.txt' w
        FileWrite $1 $R0
        FileClose $1

        ${DriveSpace} "$0" "/D=F /S=M" $R3
        WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 6' 'Text' \
        '$R3 Mb'
        ReadIniStr $0 '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 6' 'HWND'
        SendMessage $0 ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 'STR:$R3 Mb'

        Abort

     next:
        ReadIniStr $0 '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 2' 'State'
        StrCpy '$INSTDIR' '$0'
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Already did it. I just can't mark the +1 cause I don't have enough reputation.